# C - structures and lists

Tags: c, arrays

I want to save the cartesian product of two arrays into one multidimentional array.

`arr[number][0]` - number from the first array
`arr[number][1]` - number from the second array

number = sizeof(array1)*sizeof(array2)

```
int main() {
    int arr1[4] = {1, 4, 2, 3};
    int arr2[4] = {4, 1, 3, 3};
    int **outcomes = getProduct(arr1, 4, arr2, 4);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%d", outcomes[i][0]);

    getchar();
}

int* getProduct(int arr1[], int size1, int arr2[], int size2) {
    int **outcomes = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*16), count = 0, i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            outcomes[count][0] = arr1[i];
            outcomes[count][1] = arr2[j];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return outcomes;
};
```

However, this code strangly breaks while being in the nested loop inside getProduct() function. The logic is ok, I thing the problem might be with pointers.

1. Why do I need to initialize multidimentional arrays with two pointers?
2. Why isn't this code working?
3. Do u have any advices for me on how can I improve this code? ( I didn't code in C too much so I don't know which structures a "good" code uses).

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile.  Make sure you pay attention to the warning/error messages your compiler is producing.

Comment: Could you at least help me to allocate the memory for this dwodimentional array? :P

Answer (score 1):

The function `getProduct` would fail because you are assigning a pointer to an int( ie `int*`) to a pointer to an int pointer (ie  `int**`).

```
Why do I need to initialize multidimentional arrays with two pointers?
```

Because

`int**` (pointer to int pointer) - with this, we can access an element of any row and any column which is not possible with a single pointer(or single dimensional array)

Similarly `int***` can be used for three dimensional array or in other words pointer to pointer to an int pointer

```
   To improve the code
```

I think your cartesian product function should look something like this

```
int** getProduct(int arr1[], int size1, int arr2[], int size2) {
    int **outcome = malloc(sizeof(int*)*size1);        
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<size1;i++)
     outcome[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*size2);
    for(i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            outcome[i][j] = arr1[i] * arr2[j];
        }
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

And your main() like this

```
int main() {
    int arr1[4] = {1, 4, 2, 3};
    int arr2[4] = {4, 1, 3, 3};
    int **outcomes = getProduct(arr1, 4, arr2, 4);

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
     for(j = 0;j <4; j++){
        printf("%d  ", outcomes[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: what's *ptr for? It's never used.

Comment: @khernik Modified the answer removing the unnecessary *ptr.This should work fine for you. .

Comment: `int**` is **not** an "array of array"...  See e.g. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html.